# Android Jetpack Compose (Composable) Disable Hardware Acceleration for particular composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable, that is using NativeCanvas together with BlurMaskFilter for applying some custom blur effect. This is working fine for device with with API > 23, and the problem is caused by hardware acceleration for older devices.

Here you can see the blur is working on API 30 (left) and not so much on API 22 (right).

[image]

I know that I can disable it manually for the whole application or activity from the manifest file using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`.

For Views we could disable it for particular views rather than the whole activity using `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`

Is there a way we could disable the hardware acceleration for particular Composable and not for the whole application/activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [Interoperability APIs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose) you can embed `ComposeView` with the needed configuration inside your composable:

```
@Composable
fun SoftwareLayerComposable(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            ComposeView(context).apply {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
            }
        },
        update = { composeView ->
            composeView.setContent(content)
        },
        modifier = modifier,
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
SoftwareLayerComposable(Modifier) {
    // your view
}
```